# Spring Boot 1.5.10: Load Log4j2 2.10 external .properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I'm having a issue loading an external log4j2.properties file in a Spring Boot 1.5.10 application. I haven't had an issue with this before, but I'm upgrading to the latest version of log4j2 which is v2.10. Example below of how I am attempting to load the external properties (by external I mean not in the classpath).

```
File file = new File("lo4j2.properties");
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
```

The above snippet is ran in the main method on app startup. Prior to log4j2 v2.10 this worked fine but this doesn't seem to work any longer. Any help with this would be most appreciated. Thank you in advance!

UPDATE:
Well I feel extra dumb right about now lol. So the above does work, only if you supply the correct file now lol :)